# Is editing Java entity files equivalent to generating then in Spring Roo?

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo

Is editing Java entity files equivalent to generating then in Spring Roo?
Can I add more fields to it manually?

The things is that I already have entities and I just want everything else generated by Roo, can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can make the modification in the entity. Roo can understand that.

Make sure you have, Roo running, if you are running all your commands from command line.

Check the following line in your persistence.xml to get your schema updated.

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can edit later, too. But there are a lots of important points:

1. Database. If you add new fields, then you should modify the relevant database table. Or the persistence.xml file. What kind of DB do you use?
2. Have you already any special code in service classes and repository classes? It's possible that you need to modify the code there.
3. Have you any special code that is not handled in Roo?
4. Have you already unbounded the Roo? Or from other hand, do you use STS with Roo?

Comment: I was trying to ask if Roo would generate DB, mapping and everything else for me from my Java code modifications

Comment: No, Roo will not generate DB. Your project will generate it by first run if you use good settings.

Roo creates only the connection, session, etc to a DB that you specify in database.properties.